# How to store thousands of CSV files on Hadoop HDFS

Tags: json, csv, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

**What's the situation?** 
I have ten thousands of CSV files (each 250kb - 270kb) that I would like to process using Spark (Pyspark to be precise). Each CSV file represents process data for one specific event. You could say that one CSV file represents one object. Since I want to store the data on HDFS I have to find a way to concatenate the data (since it's inefficient to store large amounts of tiny data on HDFS).

Snippet of one CSV file (simplified).

```
Time        Module  v1   v2      v3     v4  v5   v6      v7     v8
00:00:00    Start   0   26,2    26,0    0   0   25,899  25,7    0
00:00:06    2: M1   0   26,1    26,2    0   0   25,8    25,899  0
00:01:06    2: M1   0   26,6    26,6    0   0   26,8    26,799  0
00:02:05    2: M1   0   27,1    27,0    0   0   27,7    27,7    0
00:03:06    2: M1   0   27,3    27,5    0   0   28,1    28,1    0
```

The full data has 45-50 columns and around 1000 rows.

**My idea so far.**
I was thinking of transforming each CSV into one JSON object and then concatenate the JSON objects as seen below

```
{
 "Event": "MLV14092",
 "Values": [
  {
   "Time": "00:00:00",
   "Module": "Start",
   "v1": "33.299"
   ...
  },
  {
   "Time": "00:00:06",
   "Module": "2: M1",
   "v1": "33.4"
   ... 
  }
 ]
}
```

**Question.** **Is that a valid approach?** I'm relatively new to the Hadoop environment and I've done some tutorials with JSON files. However in those tutorials I was always able to store one JSON object in one line and therefore I didn't have to worry at what line HDFS splits the file. With one JSON object being so "big", it won't fit into a single line. **Is there a better way to proceed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would not want to store many small files in HDFS -- small being files < ~64-128MB in size.

From your description, it also looks like the "Event" name/id will be very important, but it is not part of the existing csv files (i.e. it's in the filename, but not in the file).

Given that the size and number of the files is still not that large, have you considered writing a small shell or Python script to do the following:

- Remove the header from each csv
- Prepend/append a column to each csv containing the "Event" name/id
- Store the result in a new file

You would apply the script to each each file, which would give you a transformed output file. (Your script could also do this to the entire set or subset of files in batches)

You could then concatenate the transformed output files and store the concatenated file(s) in HDFS. The concatenated file(s) would be space-efficient, line-delimited and be well-suited for exploration and analysis using tools such as PySpark/Spark and Hive.

On a separate note, there are more-optimal, file formats than CSV for such analysis, but consider exploring the columnar file format topic after this initial set of steps. For Spark, you may want to look into later storing this data in Parquet format, and for Hive, in ORC format. You could convert the data into those formats using the very same tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't consider csv to be an option due to the fact that the data will be split and distributed on the nodes and therefore Node A might have parts of Event A while Node B has the rest of Event A. This however actually is no issue and I will try to implement your idea.

Comment: On data for a specific event getting split between Nodes: Generally for the case you are describing, this is not going to be an issue; the amount of record/observation data per Event name/id is low. You will likely be performing some common analysis on each set of records, grouped by Event name/id -- when doing that grouping operation, it will shuffle and place all data corresponding to the same Event name/id on the same Node.